# Realm: Create users without logging-in

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'm working on a family sharing app, using a **Syned Realm**, where there will be 1 admin and other members created by the admin.

Admin will be able to set the `roles & permissions` of other members. Each member can have `View/Edit/Add` permission tied to them. The admin when signing-up for the app will send out invitations to the email-id's that he wants to invite and will set the necessary permissions for them.

I'd like to know if there is a way to completely handle this from the client side using Realm. From what I've read, the admin should know the `User-ID's` to be able to set the permission and the other members should know the `Admin User-ID` to access/edit the shared realm.

Initial thought was to create all the member users by the admin using `SyncUser.logIn()`. But that causes a problem as `SyncUser.logIn()` asynchronously log them in to the Realm Object Server which will cause the **admin user to logout**.

**What would be the best approach to do this? Is there a way for the admin to create users without actually logging-in them?**

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I would say that there is no API that allows the admin user to register other users on the client side since this functionality already exists in the Dashboard.

Comment: @MarinTodorov Oh I see. What do you think will be the best way to do this then?

Comment: With the current API it should be a 2 step process. 1) the admin logs in the Dashboard and creates as many users as they want. 2) the admin invites the users to the realm files they are supposed to access - this can be done from an iOS, Android, or Node.js app